# Emacs Tabulation shortcut utility

Tags: intellij-idea

What is exactly the "Emacs tab" shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA ?

I find it using the feature search, but I don't really understand what it does and what is its utility ? I tried it but it doesn't do anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action reindents the current line, or (for languages like Python where indentation has a semantic meaning) toggles between possible levels of indentation for the current line.